# Looking for a standalone and open source Social Login Library for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, open-source, dotnetopenauth, facebook-social-plugins

I am looking for a stand alone and open source "Social Login" library for ASP.NET MVC, which supports most of the popular social sites such as Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo, Linked In, and Google.

I know there are some websites which provide this kind of online services (janrain.com), but they are not free.

I know FB and Google supports OpenId, and the rest is also can be integrated using their web services. However, I prefer to use a single library to not make the code too complicated.

Please help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) is the way to go.  It fully supports openId and OpenAuth specs (1 and 2) and is well respected within the community.

[DevDefined.OAuth](https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth) is another option.  I've never used it myself, so I can't give you any information about it, but it might be worth looking into.